# Onkeypress slideshow with description change

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I'm here for help. I'm creating some onkeypress wannabe slideshow using javascript. Code I used is down there. I'd like to add some description to the photos I used and I want it to change to correspond with the current picture, so when I have "picture 1", text "description 1" is shown, then "picture 2" and "description 2" appears etc... Any suggestions, please?
Thanks for help!
PS.: If youre willing to help me, please keep in mind, that I have no idea what I'm doing...

```
let images = ["https://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/189578_205761_4_-Yuan-Peng-China-Shortlist-Professional-Sport-2017-Sony-World-Photography-Awards-58c68fa8b4532__880.jpg", 
      "https://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/212367_227257_1_-Adi-Bulboac-Romania-Shortlist-Professional-Architecture-2017-Sony-World-Photography-Awards-58c68fe283e62__880.jpg", 
      "https://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/217609_232497_0_-Wilson-Lee-China-Shortlist-Open-Competition-Still-Life-2017-Sony-World-Photography-Awards-58c68fed34611__880.jpg"];

    function changeImage(dir) {
        let img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
        img.src = images[images.indexOf(img.src) + (dir || 1)] || images[dir ? images.length - 1 : 0];
    }

    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode == '37') {
            changeImage(-1) //left <- show Prev image
        } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
            // right -> show next image
            changeImage()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download this [jQuery-sliderResponsive](https://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Background-Slider-Plugin-jQuery-sliderResponsive.html) and call the function on your key up and key down. The code work for only this slider.

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '37') {
        prevSlide(); // Previous
    } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
        nextSlide(); // Next
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an existing plugin.
However, if you would like to go on this path you could have another array with the descriptions, matching the positions.
Something like this should work:

```
let descriptions = ["It hurts!", "This is a room with small chairs (no kidding!!)", "Painting?"];
let currentIndex = 0;

function changeImage(dir) {
        // Get the index
    let img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
    let newIndex = currentIndex + dir;
    currentIndex = images[newIndex] != undefined ? newIndex : (dir > 0 ? 0 : images.length-1);

    // Change the picture
    img.src = images[currentIndex];

    // Change the description
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = descriptions[currentIndex];
}

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '37') {
        changeImage(-1) //left <- show Prev image
    } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
        // right -> show next image
        changeImage(1)
    }
}
```

Here is the example code:
https://jsfiddle.net/fwgk7stt/